# How to add an executable jar file to my project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have an executable JAR file that was provided for my project.
When I place the JAR file in a folder along with another folder that contains all the .class files that I made and run this command in the cmd:
java -jar jar_name.jar  
It works just fine.
But how can I run the project with this JAR file when working with Eclpise

Comment: Do you want your application to start that jar?

Comment: the question is unclear, please add some more information. Moreover, I think you want to trigger the main class of he executable jar using your project code...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Not sure, if you just want to add a jar to your build path. Can you please elaborate on your question.

Comment: The JAR file that was provided contains the GUI for a simple game.
The project itself is the implementation of all the rules of the game and all of the commands. I implemented the classes according to a specific API so that the JAR file could run without errors. And like I said it works when I run it from the CMD. In one of the classes of the project I have a main method that runs the game but there is no calling for the GUI file anywhere. It is one of my first project in Java so I don't know what exactly this command ( java -jar jar_name.jar) does. But I was asked to do so and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple project environment, you might have a `lib/` directory, where you can put the JAR file. In this example, the JAR file is called `MyJar.jar`:

[image]

Now, add the `MyJar.jar` file to the project's build path (right-click `Build-Path -> Add to Build-Path`):

[image]

Now right-click on the project itself and choose: `Run As -> Java Application`.

Result: The executable JAR file runs.